# frontend: using data from table related to a different table based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Update: solution added. Simpler than what I let my head get around to.

I have a table that I am creating dynamically using an API endpoint (/listpotato).
this table has the id: #potato_list
and returns:

```
{name: 'id', has_sort: true},
{name: 'type_id', label: 'potato type id' value: (o)=> {... something goes here...} },
{name: 'title', label: 'potato name', has_sort: true, action: (o)=>
                     @enterPage 'potato', o.id 
             },
```

I have a second table with an endpoint (/listpotatotype), #potatotype_list
and returns:

```
{name: 'id', has_sort: true},
{name: 'label', label: 'potato type label' },
{name: 'has_magicPower', label: 'has magic power', is_boolean: true},
```

I want to display the value of the label (which is a string and gives a text name to the type of potato) from #potatotype_list instead of displaying the id value of type_id in #potato_list. How do I do that?

I know is more straightforward to do it directly in the backend, but I suppose, for this particular task, to do it through the front-end and I am clearly an idiot because I have not been able to come up with a useful solution to the whole day. I am using coffeeScript (for reasons too long to explain) and jQuery and I am really short knowledged of both.

I tried mapping it inside an anonymous function inside the value: function of the type_id object, but I did not manage to get the data from /potatotype_list in there so I kept getting undefined.

I tried by calling the potatotypelist API in after returning /listpotato, but the jquery is giving me null / undefined.

```
    .then () => 
            return @api.listpotatotype() 
    .then (potato_types)=>
            $u = $('#ui_potatoes #potato_list')
            console.log($u)
            $el = $u.find("input[name='type_id']").val()
            console.log($el)
```

HTML

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/sprintf.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id='ui_potatos' class='ui_page'>
        <h1>Potatos</h1>
        <table id='potato_list' class='ui_block'></table>
  </div>

</body>

Any pointer in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: Can you show your html ? Also , please show excepted output as well .

Comment: Hi @Swati the expected output is: the value of 'label'  from the (#potatotype_list) which is an array of objects,  replacing the 'type_id' value in #potato_list.

Comment: Your table has `input[name='type_id']`  or not ? I am not seeing that in your table .

Comment: It does but it is created dynamically through a different function. Anyways I found the solution, will update my post. Thanks for the interest. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone else:

```
#small loop changes type_id in #drop_list to type label 

        potatos_types = await @api.listpotatotype()   
        li = {}
        for item in potatos_types then li[item.id]=item.label
```

which then is added in the #potato_list:

```
{name: 'id', has_sort: true},
{name: 'type_id', label: 'potato type id' value: (o)=> return {li[o.type_id]} },
{name: 'title', label: 'potato name', has_sort: true, action: (o)=>
                     @enterPage 'potato', o.id },
```